# Python RegExp Исключение составных слов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки! Начал я изучать на досуге RE. И появилась у меня проблема связанная с тем что бы откинуть составные слова.

```
(?<=(Молоко)|(Хлеб)|(Тольятти))(.*)$
```

Входные данные:

```
Хлебзавод производит Хлеб это очень полезный и питательный продукт
Молокозавод производит Молоко. продукт богатый кальцием
Тольяттихлеб находиться в г. Тольятти на ул. Компартии 11
Тольяттихлеб находиться в г. Тольятти. на ул. Компартии 11
Тольяттихлеб находиться в г. Тольятти., на ул. Компартии 11
```

Что хочется получить на выходе:

```
group(1)="Хлеб" group(2)=" это очень полезный и питательный продукт"
group(1)="Молоко" group(2)=". продукт богатый кальцием"
group(1)="Тольятти" group(2)=" на ул. Компартии 11"
group(1)="Тольятти" group(2)=". на ул. Компартии 11"
group(1)="Тольятти" group(2)="., на ул. Компартии 11"
```

А по факту получается:

```
group(1)="Хлеб" group(2)="завод производит Хлеб это очень полезный и питательный продукт"
group(1)="Молоко" group(2)="завод производит Молоко. продукт богатый кальцием"
group(1)="Тольятти" group(2)="хлеб находиться в г. Тольятти на ул. Компартии 11"
group(1)="Тольятти" group(2)="хлеб находиться в г. Тольятти. на ул. Компартии 11"
group(1)="Тольятти" group(2)="хлеб находиться в г. Тольятти., на ул. Компартии 11"
```

Еще я был бы крайне признателен, если бы подсказали как в результатах избавиться от паразитных: "пробелов", "." ,".," и т.д. но это не критично.
Пробовал использовать \b но он не работает, если я правильно понял из документации то в () он считается как - backspace
Еще использовал конструкцию (,|.| ) после искомого слова, оно конечно работает, но мне кажется, что это не совсем красивое решение и появляется лишняя group() а эта проблема у меня только с парой-тройкой слов из нескольких десятков и из-за них остальное переписывать не особо хочется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\b(Молоко|Хлеб|Тольятти)\b(.*)$
```

Метасимвол `\b` - граница "слова" не позволит стать совпадением составным словам.
Поставив его слева и справа от слова получим желаемый результат.

```
import re
regex = re.compile( '\\b(Молоко|Хлеб|Тольятти)\\W+(.*)$', re.M )
text = """Наш завод производит Хлеб это очень полезный и питательный продукт
Молокозавод производит Молоко. продукт богатый кальцием
Тольяттихлеб находиться в г. Тольятти на ул. Компартии 11
Тольяттихлеб находиться в г. Тольятти. на ул. Компартии 11
Тольяттихлеб находиться в г. Тольятти., на ул. Компартии 11"""
print( regex.findall( text ) )
```

Результат:

```
[('Хлеб', 'это очень полезный и питательный продукт'), ('Молоко', 'продукт богатый кальцием'), ('Тольятти', 'на ул. Компартии 11'), ('Тольятти', 'на ул. Компартии 11'), ('Тольятти', 'на ул. Компартии 11')]
```

http://ideone.com/gjchVv

Ретроспективная проверка не нужна в Вашем регулярном выражении- в питоне она выдает ошибку компиляции из-за переменной длины альтернативы.

P.S. Не забудьте использовать регулярное выражение с флагом `UNICODE` для python 2.x.
P.P.S. Данное регулярное выражение без "паразитных" символов. В предыдущей ревизии этого ответа- с ними, если надо.

Comment: да, теперь это работает в Python

Comment: Да, извините. Редко пользуюсь Питоном, а в нем есть свои нюансы. Я привык к полноценному PCRE.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Все отлично работает. Теперь осталось навести лоск и будет красота. Еще раз большое спасибо, а то сам выткал 2 дня и делал через search.